# Accessing base url php in hosting cpanel

Tags: php, api, file-upload, slim, base-url

I am using this in localhost

```
 if (isset($_FILES['image'])) {
                if(isset($_POST['directory'])){
                    $directory = $app->request->post('directory');
                    $full_directory_path = '../' . $directory;

                    //Pengecekan folder, sudah tersedia atau belum
                    if(!is_dir($full_directory_path)){

                        //Pembuatan folder baru
                        mkdir($full_directory_path, 0777, true);
                    }
                    //Menentukan tempat file akan disimpan
                    $gambar='http://192.168.0.12/task_manager/'.$directory. '/' . basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
                    $target_path = $full_directory_path . '/' . basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
                    if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {

                        //File gagal dipindahkan ke server, biasanya karena folder yang dituju tidak tersedia
                        $response['kode'] = 1;
                        $response['pesan'] = "File tidak dapat dipindahkan ke server";
                        echo json_encode($response);
                    }else{
                        // File berhasil diupload
                        $response['kode'] = 2;
                        $response['gili'] = $gambar;
                        $response['pesan'] = "File berhasil diupload";
                        echo json_encode($response);
                    }
                }else{

                }
            } else {

                //Jika file tidak terkirim dari android
                $response['kode'] = 0;
                $response['pesan'] = 'File tidak terkirim ke server';
                echo json_encode($response);
            }
```

and it works perfectly, but when I put it in my hosting it cannot insert image. I think it is because of this

```
$full_directory_path = '../' . $directory;
```

how can I access base url in cpanel? did it true like that? cause in localhost it is works perfectly

this is my structure path : public_html/api/task_manager/v1/index.php
what I want is making new path under public_html so how can I change my url like this `$full_directory_path = 'http://myweb/' . $directory;`
$directory will make new directory

Comment: I am using like this $full_directory_path = 'http://myweb/' . $directory; but not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$full_directory_path = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/task_manager/'. $directory;
```

Comment: your suggestion surely make new directory appear but dont transfer the image. I edited my answer with file structure in my hosting

Comment: @PhilipusSilaen I added myweb subdir to the path. You know the path - just use it. You know, how to get the base.

Comment: im trying like this $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/myweb.com/'. $directory; still not transfer the image but it create this folder public_html/api/task_manager/anakacara.com/$directory

Comment: @PhilipusSilaen Put this at the beginning of the script: `print __FILE__; print $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];` and show the output here.

Comment: /home/anakacar/public_html/task_manager/v1/index.php/home/anakacar/public_html

Comment: it makes new directory but it is not transfer the images. I test in localhost it works fine, did it maybe because my hosting configuration?

Comment: @PhilipusSilaen Try my new path. The images must be there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113156/discussion-between-user4035-and-philipus-silaen).